# where to find more durable engine mounts for big HP 93 Toyota Supra Turbo

Tags: motor-mounts

I've come across a 4th generation 1000+rwhp Supra with a big single turbo conversion, stock rear end, stock transmission, and Nitto drag radials.  After repeated trips to the dragstrip, we expected the rear end/factory torsen LSD to give up the ghost first but rather, the car insists on killing the factory engine mounts.  We upgraded to polyurethane engine mounts and these are getting killed as well.  What is a good aftermarket alternative to hold all this power?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.titanmotorsports.com/raceparts.html

Oh yeah... do you know what a 400, 750 and 1000 hp Supra all have in common?

They all run 12's. :D

Comment: lol!  and the respective trap speeds are 115mph, 135mph, and 155mph

Comment: Interesting - I was expecting a much faster time. My Forester STi has just under 400hp and it manages a 12.3 - and it's a bus! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do, you can get solid Billet Aluminum motor mounts from BIC Performance as well as polyurethane mounts. Polyurethane have more NVH (noise, vibration, harshness) over the stock motor mounts, but much less than full solid mounts.